# How can I get the previous location of moved files using applescript and folder actions

Tags: directory, applescript, action

I would like to write a folder action Applescript that checks where are the moved files from. Something like this:

```
    on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            
            set oldPath to the *previous location* of added_items
            display dialog "oldPath: " & oldPath as string
        end tell
    on error errorMessage number errorNumber
        display dialog "errorMessage: " & errorMessage & ", errorNumber: " & errorNumber
    end try
end adding folder items to
```

How can I do this in a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately**, it is not possible to get information about where files are being dragged to watch-folder from in direct way.

The only solution I could suggest is to create an additional **droplet** (myDroplet.app) for **watch-folder** with something like the following code. By dragging files to this droplet instead of dragging them to the watch-folder, you will achieve the desired effect.

Also, you can remember the path of the old folder to the **clipboard**, if you need to use it in the **on adding handler** of the watch-folder.

```
on open dropped_items
    tell application "Finder"
        set watch_Folder to (path to desktop as text) & "Watch_Folder"
        set item1 to item ((item 1 of dropped_items) as Unicode text)
        set oldPath to POSIX path of (container of item1 as alias)
        display dialog "oldPath: " & oldPath -- or,
        set the clipboard to oldPath
        move dropped_items to folder watch_Folder replacing yes
    end tell
end open
```

In the **on adding handler** of the watch-folder, you will get the old path from the clipboard:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    set oldPath to the clipboard as text
    -- other stuff
end adding folder items to
```

If your watch-folder receives downloaded files from the Internet, then the old path is naturally the path of the watch-folder itself.

Also, I don't know the details of the task for which you need the watch-folder solution. Personally, I would solve a similar problem for myself by completely abandoning the watch-folder and switching to a pure droplet solution.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. I have updated the answer. It may not be very satisfying, but at least it works.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to find out the original path of files or folders that have been thrown into the trash bin? The system has to store it somewhere, otherwise they couldn't be put back to the original place either.